# Suppress SplitView for iPad in XCode project settings

Tags: swift, xcode

My app cannot be used in split view on the ipad, so neither can I open other windows next to my app, nor can I use my app next to other apps in splitivew (1/3, 1/2, 2/3).

The funny thing is that I checked this at the beginning of the project and everything worked. Now it doesn't work anymore, even if I comment out all content in my main view and only display one text I can't use splitview.

Is it possible to not programmatically prohibit the use of splitview somewhere in the project settings, because I'm afraid that over time I have banned this functionality alongside.
In info I have allowed all 4 interface orientations for iPad I. I use SwiftUI and Xcode 13.4.

Comment: Did you uncheck the box that says “this app requires full screen”?

Comment: Thank you very much, that has been it. You have saved me a lot of time